# How can I pass in tag data from my controller to my view into a js function?

Tags: spring-mvc, jstl

I'm passing in a string of data from my controller into my view and accessed as such.

myview.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
<body>
    <div>${myDataString}</div>
    ...
    <div id="container"></div>  <!-- js func populats this -->
```

How can I pass this data into a js function from within my view?

```
<script type="text/javascript">         
 $(function () {
   var temp = ${myDataString};  // <-- How can I access or passin the string data?
$('#container').buildStuffWithMyDataString({
o o o
```

Comment: What is your problem? Does `var temp = '${myDataString}';` solve your problem? (just enclose `${myDataString}` with single quote)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing single ticks

'${myDataString}' fixed it.